# Get the absolute path in C# and bind the path dynamically to a image element using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net

I want to display images I retrieve from the database.

In my database I have saved the absolute URL in the imagepath field and while I am retrieving I am getting the relative path with double slash instead. I want this '\'. how do I get the absolute path?

Another question is I have the image placeholder in my ASP.NET web page I want to set the imagepath with the path I retrieve from the database. How do I do that using jQuery or any other method??

I tried using this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SecondAd1").attr("src", "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Pictures\image.jpg");
});
```

But couldn't, how could I do this?

Comment: what are trying to develop. A web application only for you on your local machine?

Comment: no a website which has this feature user to upload image at one page then displaying those images on another page

Comment: am getting this path say  ..\image\module1\img.jpg i want to set this path for the src attribute of the image..but it fails to load that image.

Comment: then you need to save your files in your web servers document root or below (App_Data) and best only save relative paths in your database.

Comment: ya daniel am saving the relative path in db but while i retrieve i concatenate root folder to it and try to display the image

Comment: have a look at `HttpServerUtilityBase.MapPath()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question:
If you want to replace in the server (C#):

```
string stringWithoutDoubleSlash = stringWithDoubleSlash.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

If you want to do it in the client (Javascript):

```
var stringWithoutDoubleSlash = stringWithDoubleSlash.replace(/\\/g, "\\");
```

For your second question, your code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SecondAd1").attr("src", "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Pictures\\image.jpg");
});
```

That's because `'\'` is a javascript special character for escaping, so we have to prepend another `'\'`.

Just a comment: You're using local paths, so your images will load only on your pc.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

u should store the retrieved images into a folder inside your website's root folder